# in the early January or in early January

Tags: learning

I am confused with the use of "early." For example, I heard people say that I will be back early January. But on the internet, I saw people use it with proposition "in" and some even put "the" in front of the month indicated. Could anyone explain the nuance among these usages? Thanks.

Lee

Comment: This reminds me of American "I wrote my mother" and British " I wrote to my mother". I don't think it's something to worry about. I would write "in early January" as being more correct (to me) but would readily miss out the *in* when speaking.

Comment: Worth looking at the 'Is it common to omit a preposition (in / on / of) before “the month (year / week /day) when they are used adjectively and adverbially?' thread for other usages.

Comment: You never use "the early January".  You might use "the early Spring".  Apparently giving the month is too specific to need an article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"I will be back early January" is an [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) (an omission of a word or phrase) of "I will be back in early January." "I will be back in the early January" is incorrect; perhaps someone was trying to say "I will be back in the *beginning* of January," which would be correct.

Comment: Your link defines ellipsis as one or more words omitted from a clause. Yet 'in early January' is, in my knowledge, not a clause. Is 'early January' being used in some other way, perhaps as an adverb?

Comment: On the other hand, Collins has a far broader definition: ellipsis: n, pl -ses 
1. (Grammar) Also called: eclipsis: omission of parts of a word or sentence